# convert from posix timestamp in %Y-%m-%d in R

Tags: r, date, unix, time

i have date in this format:

```
1397758632
```

and i need to convert them into dates in this format %Y-%m-%d.
how can i do this? my timezone is GTM.
Using as.POSIXct() function in this way:

```
as.POSIXct(x="1397758632",origin="1960-01-01", tz="GMT")
```

i have this error

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) :    character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

how can i obtain a readable data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things, if you have defined a variable `x = "1397758632"` you don't have to declare it again, just use `x`. eg//  `as.POSIXct(x,origin="1970-01-01", tz="GMT")`

2nd, `x="1397758632"` is actually a char variable, try `str(x)` you would want to declare it as numeric, `x=1397758632` and you should be all good.

Lastly, add `as.Date()` if you just want the date and not the whole time stamp.

So something like:
`x=1397758632
as.POSIXct(x,origin="1970-01-01", tz="GMT")
as.Date(as.POSIXct(x,origin="1970-01-01", tz="GMT")) # for just the date`

Comment: thanks a lot, i didn't noticed that i was passing a string and not a numeric. 
I have another question, what if i chang origin time? i get always the same results?

Comment: If you remove the tz `as.POSIXct(x,origin="1970-01-01")` it will use your `Sys.time()` to set the timezone. Truthfully, I don't know as I am just used to adding the offset in seconds rather than remembering what the tz codes are. eg// your date +/- offset. Set origin to 1970, your results are 10 years behind using 1960 (assuming you are looking at data from this year) and try this for offsets it is pretty straight forward to remember once you know what time zones you work with regularly.  http://www.epochconverter.com/epoch/timezones.php?epoch=1398163877